# Can HTML5 in my asp.net/Razor project affect functionality?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, razor

This may seem like, or even be, a strange question, but: could changing the HTML version this way (in my _Layout.cshtml file):

```
@*<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">*@
<!DOCTYPE html> @* Commented out the above 5/6/2013 to make this HTML5, as is _Layout_telerik.cshtml *@
```

...break (or enhance) my project's functionality? I'm experiencing some odd behavior, and today updated my jQuery version (from 1.4.4 and 1.6.2 to 1.9.1); also updated jQuery-ui. So, I'm wondering if trotting out the shinier version of HTML might alter behavior, too.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your audience is using IE7 or below, there might be a few things that don't render as expected but nearly all of the newer features of HTML5 will be either ignored or compensated by the newer browsers.

I think it'll do nothing but help as you're modernizing your pages.

I've been using  in all of my pages for a year and have had no complaints.